# Is there any way to run a php script by clicking on a li tag using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I am trying to create an addFriend() function that only activates when an `li` tag within the HTML is clicked. This is my very simple HTML block that is relevant to the question:

```
<li id="add_friend" onclick="addFriend();">Add friend</li>
```

This is my javascript function that is called when the `li` tag is clicked. I am using a get request for the ajax response.

```
function addFriend() {
    document.getElementById("add_friend").innerHTML = "please wait...";

    //ajax
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.open("GET", "php/friend.php", true);

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("add_friend").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
       }
   };
   ajax.send();
}//END addFriend
```

This is what friends.php looks like.  It just a temporarily test function

```
<?php
    echo "This is a test";
?>
```

I just threw an echo within the php script to check if there was a response.  However every time I click on the `li` tag I receive a 500 error on the `ajax.send();` line of code in the javascript. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at your server's error log (since that is where the details of server errors are recorded). You need to find out what the actual error is. The server won't tell the browser what errors PHP is throwing.

Comment: Why are you setting a Content-Type request header for a GET request? There is no content to describe the type of!

Comment: Why are you testing if the request has finished loading **or** if it has a 200 status? Normally you'd want both.

Comment: ok so I got rid of the content type request header and also checking for both status and ready state. still get a 500 error.  checking error log now.

Comment: I used your code and didn't find any problem. Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/ybague99/1/.